# what is the tensorflow equivalent for pytorch probability function: torch.bernoulli?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

In Pytorch, you can do following:

```
x = torch.bernoulli(my_data)
```

Any similar functionality in tensorflow? Can the input be 2-D tensor, such as (batch, len)?

## I tried tensorflow.contrib.distributions.Bernoulli:

```
import numpy as np
tmp_x1 = np.random.rand(20,5) 
new_data_2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(tmp_x1)
from tensorflow.contrib.distributions import  Bernoulli
tmp2_x1 = Bernoulli(probs=new_data_2)
```

## got error:

```
return math_ops.log(probs) - math_ops.log1p(-1. * probs), probs
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'Tensor'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems [`tf.distributions.Bernoulli`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distributions/Bernoulli) does what you need.  The input can be an N-D tensor, which includes a 2D tensor.

**EDIT: example use**

After your comment, I tried the following, which worked for me (using tensorflow 1.11):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.distributions import  Bernoulli

tmp_x1 = np.random.rand(20,5)
new_data_2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(tmp_x1)
tmp2_x1 = Bernoulli(probs=new_data_2)
sess = tf.Session()
print sess.run(tmp2_x1.sample())
```

Comment: I tried:import numpy as np
tmp_x1 = np.random.rand(20,5) 

new_data = (1-0.1)*(tmp_x1*0.0 +1.0)
print(new_data.shape[0])
for i in range(new_data.shape[0]):
    one = np.random.randint(0, new_data.shape[1]-1)
    new_data[i][one] = 1     #new_data[i][one] = 1
new_data_2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(new_data)
from tensorflow.contrib.distributions import  Bernoulli
tmp2_x1 = Bernoulli(probs=new_data_2)

Comment: error:    return math_ops.log(probs) - math_ops.log1p(-1. * probs), probs

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'Tensor'

Comment: Do not put code in the comment, it's not readable. Instead you can modify and add it in the question.

Comment: @jimsha I have updated the answer with a working example

Comment: Thnx Matt!, solved my problem, and works after upgrade to tf version 1.11